# Version of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with two variables in the lower limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I have a question on calculus problem that I have not seen a former answer to.

So if I am given an integral of the form $\int_{2y-x}^\infty (2\pi t)^{-1/2} e^{-z^2 /(2t)} dz$, which is a probability distribution, and I wish to obtain its joint pdf of $x,y$ then I need to differentiate the integral $\partial^2/\partial x \partial y$.

However, I can't understand why this works. From elementary calculus we can deal with the single variable case using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but why can we differentiate this and get $\displaystyle\frac{2(2y-x)}{t\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}~$?

Comment: Apply Chain Rule.

Comment: @geetha290krm Chain rule would be like $(y,x)\to u$ composed with $u \to \int_{2y-x}^\infty (2\pi t)^{-1/2} e^{-z^2/(2t)} dz$. But I can't see how to use it in this case. Could you please write an answer to how chain rule works here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
F(x,y) = \int_{2y-x}^{\infty} g(z) dz
\quad \text{with} \quad
g(z) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2t}}.
$$

Note, to avoid confusion, we use $g(z)$ to denote the integrand, and we still use $f(x,y)$ to denote the joint PDF. We know the relationship between joint CDF and joint PDF:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}$$

We use $F$ to denote $F(x,y)$ to keep the derivation neat. Let's do $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ first, define $u=2y-x$

$$
F= \int_{u}^{\infty} g(z) dz= -\int^{u}_{\infty} g(z) dz
$$

and apply chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

From Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}=-g(u)$$

Note $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-1$, hence,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=-g(u)\cdot(-1)=g(u)=g(2y-x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}$$

Next, we take partial derivative with respect to $y$,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}$$

Simplify and we get

$$\boxed{f(x,y)=\frac{2(2y-x)}{t\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are considering
$$
F(x,y) := \int_{2y-x}^{\infty} f(z) \mathrm{d} z
\quad \text{with} \quad
f(z) = (2\pi t)^{-\frac 12}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2t}}.
$$
As suggested in the comment, by the chain rule (*with your comment's notation, set $u = 2y-x$*),
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y) = - 2 f(2y-x) \quad \text{and thus} \quad
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y) = 2 f'(2y-x).
$$
Since $f'(z) = - \frac{z}{t} (2\pi t)^{-\frac 12}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2t}}$, you indeed obtain
$$
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y)
= \frac{2(2y-x)}{t\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}.
$$